# Изменить тему всего приложения в манифесте программно

Tags: java, android, xml

Как изменить тему в манифесте программно?

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/example_theme">
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. Манифест нельзя менять программно.

Вы можете только для каждой активити программно назначить стиль методом `setTheme`, вызвав его до вызова `super.onCreate()` в `onCreate методе активити.